# How a cv::Mat translate from/to a glm::mat4

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl, glm-math

We calculate the position and rotation in OpenCV, and will render it with OpenGL. So how could we translate between these two kinds of matrix(`cv::Mat` `glm::mat4`) or vectors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As they both are stored in memory in a continuous location, you can transform from one object to the other with the command '*memcpy*'.

You have to be sure to define both matrices with the same type (float in this case).

You can use these functions to make the conversion (always 4x4 matrices):

```
void fromCV2GLM(const cv::Mat& cvmat, glm::mat4* glmmat) {
    if (cvmat.cols != 4 || cvmat.rows != 4 || cvmat.type() != CV_32FC1) {
        cout << "Matrix conversion error!" << endl;
        return;
    }
    memcpy(glm::value_ptr(*glmmat), cvmat.data, 16 * sizeof(float));
}

void fromGLM2CV(const glm::mat4& glmmat, cv::Mat* cvmat) {
    if (cvmat->cols != 4 || cvmat->rows != 4) {
        (*cvmat) = cv::Mat(4, 4, CV_32F);
    }
    memcpy(cvmat->data, glm::value_ptr(glmmat), 16 * sizeof(float));
}
```

These functions are only to convert the data types, but the data structure is not changed. If you have to use the glm matrix in a OpenCV based method, you should transpose the matrix.

Comment: Surprised that they use same memory layout. However, I remember that glm use column based matrix. Might a transposition is needed?

Comment: AFAIK yes. I used this code to compare the orientation of an object in two applications, and I had to transpose the data get from the glm class to have comparable data.

Comment: You have to include the header `#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>` in order to find `glm::value_ptr`

Answer (score 2):

**DONT FORGET TO TRANSPOSE!!!!!! THIS ALMOST FxxKING KILLS ME**

```
bool fromCV2GLM(const cv::Mat& cvmat, glm::mat4* glmmat) {
    if (cvmat.cols != 4 || cvmat.rows != 4 || cvmat.type() != CV_32FC1) {
        SysUtil::errorOutput("PanoDataGenerator::Mat_CV2GLM Matrix conversion error!");
        return false;
    }
    memcpy(glm::value_ptr(*glmmat), cvmat.data, 16 * sizeof(float));
    *glmmat = glm::transpose(*glmmat);
    return true;
}

bool fromGLM2CV(const glm::mat4& glmmat, cv::Mat* cvmat) {
    if (cvmat->cols != 4 || cvmat->rows != 4) {
        (*cvmat) = cv::Mat(4, 4, CV_32F);
    }
    memcpy(cvmat->data, glm::value_ptr(glmmat), 16 * sizeof(float));
    *cvmat = cvmat->t();
    return true;
}
```